# Is Django complaining about itself in this error message?

Tags: django

When I start my server, I get:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py:7: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.contrib.admin.util module has been renamed. Use django.contrib.admin.utils instead.
  "Use django.contrib.admin.utils instead.", RemovedInDjango19Warning)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py:159: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class ContentType(models.Model):

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py:7: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.contrib.admin.util module has been renamed. Use django.contrib.admin.utils instead.
  "Use django.contrib.admin.utils instead.", RemovedInDjango19Warning)

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py:159: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
  class ContentType(models.Model):

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 14, 2015 - 19:45:18
Django version 1.8.4, using settings 'viewer.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Are the four `RemovedInDjango19Warning`s something I should ignore? I grepped my code for the mentioned issues and I couldn't find those in my code.

Comment: Another possibility is that a third party app you've installed uses something deprecated.

Comment: @chucksmash: I hadn't considered that, thanks! Looks like I have quite some checking to do.

Comment: I spotted the culprit for the 1st and 3rd errors: https://github.com/burke-software/django-mass-edit/issues/49

Comment: The django-mass-edit code has already been fixed in [issue 47](https://github.com/burke-software/django-mass-edit/issues/47), but it looks like there hasn't been a release since then. Since it's only a deprecation warning, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Alasdair: nice, didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the content types warning, make sure you have `contenttypes` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. This will be required because some code in your project (e.g in django-mass-edit) uses the `ContentType` model.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   ...
)
```

The other `django.contrib.admin.util` warning has been fixed in django-mass-edit [issue 47](https://github.com/burke-software/django-mass-edit/issues/47), but at the time of writing there hasn't been a new release yet. Since it's only a deprecation warning, you don't need to worry about it until you actually upgrade to Django 1.9.